# Populate input fields with data from vuex state in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have the following code snippet from my  app component:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Basic</h3>
    <div v-for="(field, index) in basics" :key="index">
    <input v-model="basics.name" placeholder="Name" type="text">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input v-model="basics.email" placeholder="Email" type="email">
    <br>
    <hr/>
    <button @click.prevent="addField">Add</button>
    <button @click.prevent="removeField(index)">Remove</button>
    <br>
    <button @click.prevent="back">Back</button>
    <button @click.prevent="toNext">Next</button>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "Basics",
  data() {
    return {
      basics: [{
        name: "",
        email: ""
      }]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["addBasicData"]),
    addFied(){
      this.basics.push({
        name: "",
        email: ""
      });
    },
    removeField(index){
      this.basics.splice(index, 1);
    },
    toNext() {
      this.addBasicData(this.basics);
      this.$router.push({ name: "Location" });
    },
    back() {
      this.$router.back();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

In the code above when I finish filling up the form and click next button the data is sent to the state and we are guided to another route named "Location".

When I click `back` button in the "Location" route I'm back to route named "Basic".

The issue here is when I'm brought back to the route named "Basic" the form fields are empty although they are binded with the data object.

How do I populate these input fields when I return back to same route ?

Here is the working replica of the app: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-feynman-f5gbv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div v-for="(field, index) in basics" :key="index">
    <input v-model="basic.name" placeholder="Name" type="text">
    <input v-model="basic.email" placeholder="Email" type="email">
    <button @click.prevent="removeField(index)">Remove</button>
</div>
<hr/>
<button @click.prevent="addField">Add</button>
<br>
<button @click.prevent="back">Back</button>
<button @click.prevent="toNext">Next</button>

methods: {
    addField() {
        this.$store.commit('addBasic',{name:"",email:""} )
    },
    removeField(index) {
        this.$store.commit('removeField',index )
    },
    toNext() {
        this.$router.push({ name: "Location" });
    }
},
computed: {
    basic:{
        get() {
          return this.$store.getters.getBasic;
        }
     }
}
```

store.js

```
// ...
state: {
    basic:[{name:"Jonny",email:"jonny@mail.com"}, 
           {name:"Bonny",email:"Bonny@mail.com"}]
}
mutations: {
    addBasic(state,value) {
        state.basic.push(value)
    },
    removeField(state,index ){
        state.basic.splice(index,1);
    }
 }
```

Thats just one of two versions how you can do it.
Or you can map the mutatations and call them directly in the click event.
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html

The add field button makes only sense outside of the loop.

addBasicData you dont need it

Comment: Thanks man. How do I do it if I'm using click event o add another input fields of `name` and `email` with index ??

Comment: How do you mean with index?

Comment: I've updated my code section in the above question.

Comment: Oh man thanks, this diminishes my other issues also

Comment: Glad i could help. Could you accept my answer please as the right answer ;-) hehe :)

Comment: Did a bit more of a digging and found out that we can use getters to sync with inputs

Comment: Thx bro. Can you show with the getters? You mean using getters in computed values?

Comment: `computed:mapGetters("getBasic")` or `computed:mapGetters({ basic: "getBasic" })`

Answer (score 0):

This method somehow works:

```js
  mounted() {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    let fromState = this.$store.state.Basics.basics;
    if (fromState) {
      this.basics.name = fromState.name;
      this.basics.email = fromState.email;
    }
  }
```

I will really appreciate if there are any other convenient method to achieve this.
Tried `mapState` but didn't work